# Игра "Гло́кая ку́здра"

Tags: филозабавы

***Гло́кая ку́здра ште́ко будлану́ла бо́кра и курдя́чит бокрёнка.***

Эта фраза (известны разные варианты) было изобретена в конце двадцатых Львом   Владимировичем Щербой для демонстрации возможностей некорневых морфов.

Едва ли не с тех самых пор сама идея оспаривалась. У студентов-филологов даже возникла своего рода игра: написать вполне "русскую" фразу, сохранив внешнее сходство, но полностью опровергающую трактовку автора.

Вот два примера, не говорю, что лучших, но весьма забавных.

***Малахая дыра горько кольнула турка и смешит турчонка.

Всякая шушера тихо помянула повара и аппендицит поваренка.***

Еще можно много нарыть в инете, но это не так интересно.
Есть желание самим придумать еще?

ЗЫ Знаки препинания можно игнорировать, т.к. исходная фраза всегда записывалась "со слуха".

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в чём состоит *опровержение идеи автора* - в отрицании возможностей некорневых морфов?

Comment: Не заморачивайтесь. Это игра.

Comment: я догадался, что игра. Каковы правила?

Comment: Я тоже не понял в чем опровержение. Оба приведенных примера показывают, что Щерба был прав.

Comment: И Вы - не заморачивайтесь.

Comment: Мне лично больше по нраву игры вроде

1.Three witches watch three Swatch watches. Which witch watch which Swatch watch?
2. [Косил косой косой косой косой][1].

[1]:http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: А в чем цель игры?

Comment: Собрать фразу из омонимичных слов, которая повергнет не-носителя языка в ступор. Да и носитель языка тоже может быть нокаутирован при увеличении уровня вложенности. Чего только "ши" в цикле стоят. Заодно там же по ссылке можно посмотреть раздел moar - вполне подходит под глокую куздру.

Comment: Ну положим, Ваши фразы не целиком состоят из омонимов.  
Ну да Бог с ним. Много вы сеансов такой игры можете провести?

Comment: А что такое "не заморачивайтесь"? 

Comment: Это значит, играть, видимо, не хотят, а хотят спорить о матерриях, отношения к теме не имеющих.
Что странно. Ибо забава известная. И обычно принимается, если не "на ура", то с пониманием.

Comment: А что непонятного? У Щербы фраза как бы "понятна", хотя корни бессмысленные. А здесь окончания наводят на мысль о других частях речи. Например, "малахая" можно воспринять как прилагательное (типа глухая), а "аппендицит" - как глагол. То есть окончания нас "обманывают".  

Игра интересная.

Comment: > В мантре "Ом мани падме хум" ом - ... бодхисатвы Авалокитешвары.  

Это не выдумка, а реальная фраза из книжки, кажется, по ламаизму. Русское слово в ней - только предлог "в". К сожалению, я забыла слово, обозначенное многоточием, оно тоже было чисто индийское . Типа ваджра или сандкхья или что-то в этом роде.

Answer (score 1):

Жаждая кокоса,высоко вскочила обезьяна и щекочет обезьянёнка.(Частично не моё!)

Comment: У вас не совсем выдержан вариант с уменьшительной формой. Все-таки обезьянёнок - и слово не словарное, и семантика суффикса общая, не противоречит Щербе.

Comment: Виноват,бес попутал.Больше не буду.

Comment: А мне ответ вполне нравится, хотя замечание морковкина и справедливо. Но не настолько же, чтобы ответ удалять?!

Comment: *Виноват,бес попутал.Больше не буду* - не стоит так ставить вопрос. Пишите еще.